# Proving the boundary of a closed disk in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a closed disk $G = \bar{D}[i, 1]$ in a complex plane and I am meant to determine the boundary and prove this.

The boundary of course is the circle $C[i,1]$ however I am uncertain of how to prove this.

I would like to prove this by showing that every point beyond the radius of the circle is outside $G$

ie. $\forall z \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $|z| > 1, z\notin G$

Would this be the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb C$ \ $G=G^c.$ The usual notation for the boundary of $G$ is $\partial G.$ (Also $Fr(G)$ where  $Fr$ is short for Frontier.). We have $\partial G=\overline G \cap \overline {G^c}.$

(1). If $|z-i|<1$:  Let $r=\frac {1-|z-i|}{2}.$ Then $r>0$ so $z$ belongs to the open set $B(z,r),$ which is a subset of $G$ because $$|y-z| <r\implies |y-i|\leq |y-z|+|z-i|<r+|z-i|=\frac {1+|z-i|}{2}<1.$$  So   $z\not \in \overline {G^c}$ so $z\not \in \partial G.$

(2). If $|z-i|>1$: Let $s=\frac {|z-i|-1}{2}.$ Then $s>0$ so $z$ belongs to the open set $B(z,s),$ which is a subset of $G^c$ because $$|y-z|<s \implies |i-y|\geq |i-z|-|z-y|>|i-z|-s=\frac {|i-z|+1}{2}>1.$$  So  $z\not \in \overline G$ so $z \not \in \partial G.$

(3). Therefore  $\partial G\subset \{z :|z-i|=1\}.$ It remains to show that $\{z:|z-i|=1\}\subset \partial G.$

If $|z-i|=1$:  For any real $t\in (0,1)\;$ let $z_t^-=z-\frac {1}{2}(z-i)t$ and $z_t^+=z+\frac {1}{2}(z-i).$

Then $|z-z_t^-|=|z-z_t^+|=\frac {t}{2}$ so $\{z^-_t,z^+_t\}\subset B(z,t).$

And $|z_t^--i|=1-\frac {t}{2}<1 $  so $z_t^-\in G.$

And $|z_t^+-i|=1+\frac {t}{2}>1$ so $z_t^+\in G^c.$

Any open set $U$ containing $z$ will have $B(z,t)$ as a subset for some $t\in (0,1)$, so $z_t^-\in U\cap G$  and $z_t^+\in U\cap G^c$. Therefore $z\in \overline G \cap\overline {G^c}=\partial G.$

Remark: When $|z-i|=1$ the points $z_t^-$ and $z_t^+$ lie on the line thru $i$ and $z$, with $z_t^-$ closer to $i$ than $z$ is, and with $z_t^+$ farther from $i$ than $z$ is. A little geometry is useful for many basic results about the topology of $\mathbb C.$